# Submit Cloud ML Engine job from local machine using the Python API

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have a Python scripts that defines a CMLE job like so:

```
import os
import sys
import logging
from config import Config # this holds all my config variables
from pumps import trainer
from googleapiclient import discovery, errors

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = Config.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

# The trainer folder needs to be added to PYTHONPATH for google to find it
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.pardir)+'/pumps/trainer')

training_inputs = {'scaleTier': 'BASIC',
                   'pythonModule': 'trainer.task',
                   'args': ['--bucket', Config.BUCKET_NAME,
                            '--model_dir', Config.MODEL_DIR,
                            '--transformer_dir', Config.TRANSFORMER_DIR,
                            '--data', Config.DATA_FILE,
                            '--n_estimators', '100',
                            '--class_weight', 'balanced_subsample',
                            '--criterion', 'entropy'],
                   'region': Config.REGION,
                   'jobDir': Config.JOB_DIR,
                   'runtimeVersion': Config.RUNTIME_VERSION,
                   'pythonVersion': Config.PYTHON_VERSION}


job_spec = {'jobId': Config.JOB_NAME,
            'trainingInput': training_inputs}


# the format for this variable is projects/<your_project_name>
project_id = 'projects/{}'.format(Config.PROJECT)

cloudml = discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
request = cloudml.projects().jobs().create(body=job_spec,
                                           parent=project_id)
response = request.execute()enter code here
```

Unfortunately, I get get the error `"Field: package_uris Error: Tarball URIs of the training program must be provided.">` My equvalent bash script has no problems running and it seems the Python version is missing the equivalent  `--package-path` flag. Is this a limitation of the Python API or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicated, you need to specify `package_uris`, which is the Google Cloud Storage location of the packages with the training program and any additional dependencies. If you directly call REST API to submit job, you must specify it.

Please notice that you may specify `package-path` which is a local path if you use `GCLOUD`, `GCLOUD` helps you package your training program and upload to Cloud Storage. And the Cloud Storage uris will be set to `package_uris` when `GCLOUD` submits the job to CloudML Engine.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So you're saying the Python API is incapable of pointing to a local path? If true, I find it surprising that such basic functionality is missing in the Python API